# How to avoid adding the default Locale in generated URLs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

If you follow the [I18N Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html), all generated links contain the locale parameter (localhost/en/about, localhost/fr/about). This is because we use the method `default_url_options` to always add the Locale parameter :

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  { :locale => I18n.locale }
end
```

**Is it possible to remove the locale parameter from the generated url when the locale is unknown or the default one ?**

What I need :

- Locale unknown : `mysite/about`
- Locale en : `mysite/about` (and not `localhost/en/about`)
- Locale fr : `mysite/fr/about`

I tried to only set the locale if it was not the default one, but the result is that the generated links never contain the locale parameter...

*I tried many things like this one*

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  if I18n.locale == :fr
    { :locale => I18n.locale }
  else
    { :locale => nil }
  end
end
```

---

**Whole code :**

*ApplicationController.rb :*

```
before_filter :set_locale
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale]
end

def default_url_options(options={})
  { :locale => I18n.locale }
end
```

*routes.rb*

```
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|fr/ do
  match 'about'   => 'static_pages#about',   :via => :get
  match 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact', :via => :get
  match '/' => 'search#index', :as => :search
end

root :to => 'search#index'
```

Comment: If you don't want to pass it via url, you should consider storing it in session or cookie.

Comment: I don't want to pass it in the url when the current locale is the default. When this is not the default, it is fine to have it in the url.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok I understand much better. Indeed, you almost did it.

You just need a very useful operator in Ruby: `||`

If the first value exists, it's used, otherwise the second argument is taken into account.

```
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || :en
end
```

Comment: It works ! I thought that setting nil or whatever to I18n.locale would be ignore if the locale was not supported, or nil will just be resetted to the default locale. Apparently, this is not the case. Many thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 24):

The selected answer is totally right on and provides everything you need to redirect URLs without a locale to your default locale, but I wanted to do something a bit more and figured I'd share it with you.

I wanted to avoid having to use the default locale at all, that is to say

- `mysite.com/en/page` should be the same as
- `mysite.com/page`

AND all links when viewing from the default locale should NOT include the locale, meaning mysite.com should have links that do not include the default locale (en) in them. Instead of  `mysite.com` linking to

- `mysite.com/en/page` it should link to
- `mysite.com/page`

I achieved this via the following edits to    `default_url_options`:

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  { :locale => ((I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale) ? nil : I18n.locale) }
end
```

You must define    `config.i18n.default_locale` in config/application.rb for this to work.  You can also assign fallbacks for unsupported locales via    `config.i18n.fallbacks = [ :en ]` where that array is a priority-ordered list of languages to fallback to.

Comment: Don't you think you'll have duplicate content from Google's point of view (same content exists on two different location) ?

Answer (score 4):

Rails 4 + https://github.com/svenfuchs/routing-filter

```
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
end

def default_url_options(options = {})
  (I18n.locale.to_sym.eql?(I18n.default_locale.to_sym) ? {} : {locale: I18n.locale}).merge options
end
```

Answer (score -2):

I know it's not exactly your question but...

I prefer the other way for internationalisations: **Setting the Locale from the Domain Name**

*Ex: mysite.com/about, mysite.fr/about*

For me it's the best way, but you need to buy all domains.

Comment: Yes, we want to avoid buying all the domain names.

Comment: Don't confuse languages and locales with countries.