# before_filter set_locale except controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My `routes.rb`

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
 scope '(:locale)' do
  #all resources here
 end
 namespace :blog do
  resources :posts, :only => [:index, :show]
 end
end
```

My `application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 #
 #
 before_filter :set_locale

 private

 def default_url_options(options = {})
   {locale: I18n.locale}
 end

 def set_locale
   #code for detect locale here
 end
 #
 #
end
```

All the resources inside `scope '(:locale)'` is working fine.

However **I don't want use locale with `namespace :blog`** and when I try click on blog links I can see this url `http://localhost:3000/blog/posts?locale=en`

**How can I remove locale of `namespace :blog...` and `blog resource`?. I want get a url something like `http://localhost:3000/blog/posts`** I want to remove the `?locale=en`

**Thanks!**

Comment: In your `ApplicationController`, do you have a method that looks something like `def url_options; { locale: I18n.locale }.merge(super); end` which would automatically include `locale` in your url string?

Comment: This is the method that I have in ApplicationController: `def default_url_options(options = {})
    {locale: I18n.locale}
  end` I have edited the question, If the problem is this method I want disable this method in my `PostsControllers`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `skip_before_filter` in your Blog controllers?

Comment: I have tried `skip_before_filter :set_locale` on my posts controller, but I get the same result. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Given what you said in the comments, try only including the `locale` in your `default_url_options` if the current controller is not the `PostsController`, which would hopefully get rid of the trailing
`?locale=en` issue.  Perhaps something like:

```
 def default_url_options(options = {})
   { locale: I18n.locale } unless controller_name == 'posts'
 end
```

Or, since [`default_url_options` is depreciated](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/default_url_options), if you want to use `url_options`, perhaps something like:

```
def url_options
  controller_name == 'posts' ? super : { locale: I18n.locale }.merge(super)
end
```

Neither of the above tested, so I'm not sure either of them will work.

**Edit**

How about if you set the `locale` to `nil` like in [this StackOverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5261521/567863)?  So maybe something like:

```
def url_options
  locale = controller_name == 'posts' ? nil : I18n.locale
  { locale: locale }.merge(super)
end
```

Comment: @hyperrjas, please see edit to answer.  Not sure about this solution either, unfortunately...

Comment: Thank  you with this last code I get error: `Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true` Thank you!

Comment: What happens when you set `{ locale: locale, only_path: true }.merge(super)`?

Comment: The same result with this last code. Thank you for your interest and for your help :)

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more assistance.  If you do find a solution, please update this thread!  +1 for the learning experience :-)