# Remove trailing "?" from a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this url:

```
http://localhost:3000/blog/posts?locale=en
```

I have a helper to remove `?locale=en` of url:

```
def url_without_locale_params(url)
  uri = URI url
  params = Rack::Utils.parse_query uri.query
  params.delete 'locale'
  uri.query = params.to_param
  uri.to_s
end
```

With this helper I get this url `http://localhost:3000/blog/posts?`. I would like to delete the trailing `?`.

The result should be `http://localhost:3000/blog/posts`.

Comment: The part of the URL after the question mark is called the 'query string'.

Comment: The correct answer to this is to assign `nil` to the `params` as Mike Campbell says.

Comment: It's easy to understand why you'd try using string manipulation to massage the returned URL, but, when using a class designed to manage that stuff, it's really good to take advantage of its features. URI isn't the best/most full-featured URI tool for Ruby though. Look at [Addressable::URI](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) if you want something more comprehensive.

Comment: @theTinMan I have use this feature because I can not remove the set_locale from my controller. You can take a look on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767715/before-filter-set-locale-except-controller. If there is other way remove set_locale I would be very grateful to hear your approach!. Thank you

Comment: Ruby's URI (or Addressable::URI) give you ways to remove elements from the query, and/or remove the query entirely. If you only get `?locale=en` when you receive the URL, then setting `uri.query=nil`, as Mike Campbell said, is the right thing because it will get rid of the query portion of the URL entirely. Using string manipulation after URI has worked on it would be code smell, which we sometimes have to do but it's good to avoid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answers thus far all regard the string itself. What you're actually doing is telling it that it has the params `""`. If you make it `nil` if `params.to_param == ""` you won't have that problem.

```
def url_without_locale_params(url)
  uri = URI url
  params = Rack::Utils.parse_query uri.query
  params.delete 'locale'
  uri.query = params.to_param.blank? ? nil : params.to_param
  uri.to_s
end
```

something like that should do the trick. The reason for this is that even with an empty string, URI assumes there's something to be appended, so it puts the initial `?` on.

Comment: It's correct, this response is the best. Sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 12):

Use [#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub):

```
uri = "http://localhost:3000/blog/posts?locale=en"
uri.gsub(/\?.*/, '')
  #=> "http://localhost:3000/blog/posts"
```

Answer (score 9):

[`String#chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) is a possibility.

```
1.9.3p392 :002 > "foobar?".chomp("?")
 => "foobar"
```

The final method will be

```
def url_without_locale_params(url)
  uri = URI url
  params = Rack::Utils.parse_query uri.query
  params.delete 'locale'
  uri.query = params.to_param
  uri.to_s.chomp("?")
end
```

Comment: This only works if `?` is the final character of the string. It doesn't remove characters after that.

Comment: In fact, this is what he asked. If you read his question and see the method, he's already parsing the query using `Rack::Utils`, then he generates the query string using `to_param` and here's where the trailing `?` is appended.

Comment: You're absolutely right! In that case, your answer is the best - upvoting.

Comment: Simple and elegant solution, I like it. Bravo!