# Remove "?locale=en" from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

### The goal

Remove `?locale=en` of browser's URL bar when I click on a link.

<sub>Note: there's no any asynchronous mechanism behind the process. I mean, there's no [`window.history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) modifying URL dynamically when I click something.</sub>

### The problem

Everything I'm doing isn't solving my problem.

### What I've tried

- [How to avoid adding the default Locale in generated URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261521/how-to-avoid-adding-the-default-locale-in-generated-urls)

<sub>*I'm still searching further solutions.*</sub>

### Scenario

I don't want to have a localized admin panel, then, my routing are the following:

```
scope '/(:locale)', locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
  root to: 'welcome#index'
end

namespace :admin do
  get '/' => 'home#index'

  resources :products
end
```

But I'm still always getting `?locale=en` when I click on a link inside the admin's panel. This is how I set the locale:

```
# /app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def set_locale
  extracted_locale = params[:locale] || extract_locale_from_accept_language_header

  I18n.locale = (I18n::available_locales.include? extracted_locale.to_sym) ? 
                extracted_locale : I18n.default_locale
end
```

This is my *private* `extract_locale_from_accept_language_header` method:

```
# /app/controllers/application_controller.rb
private
def extract_locale_from_accept_language_header
  request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'].scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
end
```

### Diagnose reaction

If I change this:

```
I18n.locale = (I18n::available_locales.include? extracted_locale.to_sym) ? 
              extracted_locale : I18n.default_locale
```

for this:

```
I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
```

the issue is *partially* solved. Unfortunately, this is not what I really want. I'm dealing with browser's language if there's no other option to resolve the user's locale (a.k.a. URL's locale-parameter is explicitly set).

Comment: are you trying to make Rails stop putting the locale param into urls that link to certain pages?

Comment: What do you mean by "stop putting the locale param into urls that link to certain pages"? I'm using `link_to` with `admin_path`, for instance, and the parameter automatically appears there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look at the `default_url_options` method in your application controller. This is what determines how link_to creates urls, `I18n.locale` just controls a server-side setting.  If you have a easy definition for all the pages which shouldn't get locale parameter, use it there.  For instance,

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  if params[:controller].include? "admin"
    locale: nil
  end
end
```