# Rails I18n do not include default locale in URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n, ruby-on-rails-6

**TL;DR**

I am working on a multi-language & regional Ruby-on-Rails (6.0) project. I want that the URL does not contain default locale & region (I18n), while all other languages and regions must appear.

*Current:*

mysite.com/en-us/xyz
mysite.com/es-mx/xyz

*Expected:*

mysite.com/xyz
mysite.com/es-mx/xyz

**Additional Information:**

So I am working on a multi-language application for a client, turning a simple Wordpress site into an actual Web App. Most of the requirements are taking place behind logins, and therefore I did not have a care in the world from an SEO perspective.

However, the original site was in English only. We still reuse (rebuild) several pages that are publicly accessible and rank well in Google's SERPs. We cannot lose these site, not even over the short run, so a 301 redirect won't do it.

Now what I have at the moment are URLs that target language and regions - here an extract:

- myapp.com/**en-us**/xyz
- myapp.com/**en-gb**/xyz
- myapp.com/**es-mx**/xyz
- myapp.com/**he-il**/xyz
- myapp.com/**hi-in**/xyz

Everything is fine, except I need the English US version, which is the default language and region to NOT appear in the URL.

- en-US: myapp.com/xyz     --> Default language (expected: no locale!)
- en-GB: myapp.com/**en-gb**/xyz
- es-MX: myapp.com/**es-mx**/xyz
- he-IL: myapp.com/**he-il**/xyz
- hi-IN: myapp.com/**hi-in**/xyz

I've gone through the resources available but couldn't find anything:

- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html
- [How to avoid adding the default Locale in generated URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261521/how-to-avoid-adding-the-default-locale-in-generated-urls)

Any pointers or possible solutions are much appreciated!

Comment: Check out https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator Or simply make the locale portion of your routes optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you have in your **application_controller.rb**

```
  def default_url_options
    { locale: I18n.locale }
  end
```

Try

```
  def default_url_options
    { locale: ((I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale) ? nil : I18n.locale) }
  end
```